# Asp.Net MVC3 (Razor Viewport), ValidationMessageFor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to know whether there is ValidationMessage or not. Because I want to add to "
 tag into the error message.

like

```
@if (Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId)){
 Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId) + "<br />
}
```

the above code does not work, anybody know how it make work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the ModelState for that particular error.  For example:

```
@if (ModelState["UserId"].Errors.Count > 0) {
    Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId) @:<br/>
}
```

This could get really ugly if you have it everywhere though.  If you need to do this a lot, then create a custom Html Helper extension.

Comment: Nice, I haven't seen that usage before. Might come in handy in some one-off spots

Answer (score 1):

if you need to add some markup at your validation message I would suggest you to create a custom one.
All you need to to is create a new helper and encapsulate that logic in the helper itself

somethig like the below

```
   public MvcHtmlString MyValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
         //your logic here

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. Please clarify what you want to achieve.

If you would like to show an error if there is one and do not show an error if there is not, you do not need to write separate "if()" logic like Mystere Man suggests.

Just having `Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId)` in a properly formatted by css html and having all proper references to scripts required for validation will do the trick.

By properly formatted html I mean having validation blocks next to the inputs in the div tags so that you do not have to have `<br>`s for the new lines.